# Autocad print preview not showing lines

Tags: autocad, autodesk-inventor

[image: preview]

The doors don't show up when previewed, I'm using autocad 2017. Here is a screenshot of the print preview and the main drawing.

[image]

Note: I'm still new to this.

My layer settings:

[image]

Comment: After the insertion of the layer list one can see at least that layer door has different plot style. It can be non-printable. Change the style or edit it. Plot styles tell what's printed. Separating it from what's shown on the screen gave a good amount flexibility in the era when plotters were the only way to output high quality paper drawings.